# how to redirect to a Url with a parameter from an asp.net-mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

i have an asp.net-mvc site and one of the pages is

```
http://www.mysite.com/Report
```

users can add client side filtering which generates urls like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Report?Region=US
```

i want to take a link like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/MyLastReport
```

and have a controller action that mimics as if a person added some parameters to the URL like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Report?Region=US
```

as my server side code uses:

```
 Request.Params[]
```

to filter my queries and i want to use the same code path to get the results as if the URL had these parameters on the client side.

also, is there anyway to literally do a redirect of the URL from the server side so i actually change the URL in the browser to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Report?Region=US
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the Global.asax:

```
protected void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Equals("/MyLastReport", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        Context.RewritePath("/Report?Region=US");
    }
}

public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
}
```

**UPDATE:** From controller action you can use [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) method:

```
RedirectToAction("ReportActionName", new { Region = "US" });
```

Comment: K. - i want to do this in the controller action as the filter is based on a database query